# Affect one element of a list

Tags: emacs, elisp

If I have a list of numbers

```
(setq numbers '(10 11 12))
```

and I want to increment, say, the third number, I can do this:

```
(setf (nth 2 numbers) (1+ (nth 2 numbers)))
```

But I don't like having to repeat the "(nth 2 numbers)". Is there some way I can write this but only have one reference to "(nth 2 numbers)"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a macro for exactly that:

```
(incf (nth 2 numbers))
```

You can supply the value to add as an additional argument.

Comment: That's very helpful, but it does require cl.el. I wondered if there was a general way of doing this perhaps passing in the increment function as the function to apply.

Comment: As it only needs macros, you can simply `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))`. Or if you're not worried about older versions of Emacs, make that `cl-lib` and use `cl-incf`.

Comment: Thanks - seems it needs a macro of some sort to do this whether I write one or use the CL one.

Comment: My solution doesn't use macros; only built ins.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more general answer (e.g. for some other function than `1+`), then you probably want to look at `cl-callf`.
Another option is to use `gv-ref` and `gv-deref` but that doesn't seem like a good fit for your case (it's rarely a good fit, actually).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure emacs lisp way to do it without the double call to nth...

```
(defun inc-list(n lst)
  (let ((nc (nthcdr n lst)))
    (setcar nc (1+ (car nc)))
    lst))
```